# Google Analytics Date/Hour/Time Stamp

Tags: time, google-analytics

I'm new to Google Analytics. I have a goal and I would like to see the date/hour/minute the goal occurred. Is this possible? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I could not find an answer after hours of googling...

Thanks!

Comment: This should be posted in Webmasters as it is not related to coding.

Answer (score 0):

You cant actually see the Date , hour and minute the goal in one request.

Using a [custom Report](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=PvJFc7aMS9q8nHqSmiYsLQ)

I added Hour, minute and Goal1.   Hour returned information minute returns nothing.   I tried to add date as a secondary dimension to the hour one and that also returned no information.

Remember not all of the dimensions and metrics can be combined to give information.   Hour and minute are two of them.

using a dashboard also didn't reveal any decent data.